# covariance of dependent random variables

Tags: random-variables, covariance, correlation

Assume that we have a sequence of $n$ realizations $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ of an i.i.d random variable $X$ with cdf $F_X(x)$ and pdf $f_X(x)$. Now define $Y$ as

$Y_i = \sum_{j=i}^{k} x_j, \forall i \in \{1,...,n-k+1\}$

which generates the sequence $Y_1, ..., Y_{n-k+1}$ of dependent random variables as $Y_i$ contains $k-1$ elements of $Y_{i-1}$ (and $Y_{i+1}$).

Now I want to find the covariance $cov(Y_i, Y_j), \ i \neq j$ and the covariance matrix of $Y$. As the covariance is dependent on the initial realizations $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ I am struggeling to get a general formulation.

What is the correct formulation for $cov(Y_i, Y_j)$ and **$\sum_Y$**?

Comment: What do you get for the terms $\text{cov}(X_i, X_i)$?

Comment: As $X$ is i.i.d., I would get $cov(X_i,X_j) = 0$

Comment: Better double-check that. The variance of each $X_i$ is zero? The covariance of two $Y$s will have terms like that.

Comment: $x_i$ are realizations of X, so real numbers. Should have been more precise in my above reply